# Java Menu method not working

Tags: java, do-while

I'm having an issue with this bit of code. I've been asked to create a menu system with 2 branches and an exit. When the code runs its fine the 1st time then returns to menu and regardless of whether I choose 1 or 2 it just re-runs the previous choice unless I choose exit.

```
public class Finaltuttesting {

    public static int menu() {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an option");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1: Generate Username");
        System.out.println("2: Is it a right angle?");
        System.out.println("3: Quit");
        int menansw = kboard.nextInt();
        return (menansw);
    }

    public static String userfore() {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("****** option 1 - Generate Username ********");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please enter Users Forename");
        String empfor = kboard.nextLine();
        empfor = empfor.toUpperCase();
        String initials = empfor.substring(0, 1);
        return (initials);
    }

    public static String usersur() {
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter User Surname");
        String usurname = kboard.nextLine();
        usurname = usurname.toUpperCase();
        return (usurname);
    }

    public static void displayuser(String usersur, String initials) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Username = " + usersur + initials);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String dummy = kboard.nextLine();
    }

    public static int side(int s)// asks for 3 sides of triangle
    {
        int x = 0;

        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Side " + s + ": ");
        x = number.nextInt();
        return (x);
    }

    public static int calcPower(int side) {
        int sqr = 0;
        sqr = (int) Math.pow(side, 2);
        return (sqr);
    }

    public static void rightornot(int as, int bs, int cs) {

        if (cs != (as + bs))
            System.out.println("That is not a right angled triangle.");
        else
            System.out.println("That is a right angled triangle.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            int option = 0;
            option = menu();
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                String uinitials;
                String surname;
                uinitials = userfore();
                surname = usersur();
                displayuser(surname, uinitials);
                break;
            case 2:
                int a = 0;
                int b = 0;
                int c = 0;
                a = side(1);
                b = side(2);
                c = side(3);
                int cs = 0;
                int as = 0;
                int bs = 0;
                cs = calcPower(c); // (int) Math.pow(c,2); //(c * c);
                as = calcPower(a); // (int) Math.pow(a,2);//(a * a);
                bs = calcPower(b); // (int) Math.pow(b,2);//(b * b);
                rightornot(as, bs, cs);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error - exiting program");
                System.exit(1);

            }

        } while (menu() != 3);
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is is because you're not saving/capturing the returned value from the `menu()` method and that's why you're having to call it once again in the `do-while` loop. Do something like this and it'll work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int option = 0; // declare before the loop so that you can use it in the while condition
    option = menu(); // call the menu first here once
    do {
        // int option = 0; // not needed as declared before
        // option = menu(); // not needed as called before
        ...
    } while ((option = menu()) != 3); // everytime you call to get the next option, capture it and use it to continue or terminate the loop
    // the above value in option, if not 3, will be used in the next iteration of do-while loop
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
}
```

Also, I feel that the `String dummy = kboard.nextLine();` in the `displayuser()` method is not exactly required as it just asks you to enter a dummy value anyway.